# saving and retrieving a counter in SQLiteDatabase and use it to save a unique filename

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm relatively new to Java, and want to use a counter for saving each image taken with a unique id. By saving the counter variable to SQLite, I want to retrieve it again when I restart the app with the same value as when I shut it down. The problem now is that the counter skips numbers ( saving the the filename as 0, 1, 3, 5 etc.). And it restarts from 0 when I exit and start the app again.

OnCreate, write and read in MosidaDb.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_PHOTOID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_PHOTOPATH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_AUDIOPATH + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" +
                KEY_PHOTONAME + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AUDIONAME + " INTEGER NOT NULL);");

    }


public long dbEntry2(int photoname) {
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put(KEY_PHOTONAME, photoname);
    return myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, cv2);
}

public int getPhotoid() {

    Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM NameTable", null);

    int iQuery = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHOTONAME);
    int result = 0;

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getInt(iQuery);
} 
    return result;

}
```

Do you see anything wrong in these methods? The counter variable is passed to dbEntry2, and retrieved by getPhotoid(). Or that is at least what I want it to do. thanks

Comment: Aren't the file names you are getting 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, ...?

Comment: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 now. so it seems the counter runs twice. the biggest problem however is that the counter resets when I restart the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the begining:

```
database.beginTransaction();
```

then you must call this before your application exits:

```
myDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
myDatabase.endTransaction();
```

That should commit your changes.

And also you should always close your cursor, when you are done:

```
c.close();
```

I don't know why counter skips, check your database content.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The counter skipped because I misplaced it. Got it workin